# Retrieving Firebase Notifications at the start of the app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know that, when the app is killed, it can't shows any Firebase notification... or this is what happens with my new app: I kill the app, The new notifications don't come up as well.

Now, I want to get rid of this problem in a new way: I want to retrieve, when my app starts, all the notifications the app "forgot" to see.

Here's my code

IdService

```
  public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

and the message class

```
   public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notifies(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void notifies(String body){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help)
                        .setContentTitle("Congratulations!")
                        .setContentText(body);
        Notification mNot= mBuilder.build();
// Display
        NotificationManager mNotMan = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotMan.notify(1,mNot);
    }

}
```

What can you suggest to me? Thanks for all the answers :D

Comment: If you dont set a time to live time on your message if your app does not get it then it never will. You cannot "get all missed messages" there is no such thing

Comment: Ok, so I have to set a time to live, right? On the Firebase console I set the message to be online for four weeks, but it doesn't work...

Comment: This is odd. The behavior of FCM is for it to send the message(s) as soon as the app/device is available. Is this the behavior for all the devices you tested it with?

Comment: Yeah, for every device I tested (one Cubox and a Honor7)

Comment: I can receive it only when the app is running, or while it's running in the background

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way to do this is create a notification center server side.

So , every time when you send a push notification save it on server.
When your app is starting up get push notifications list remotely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! On the emulator (Nexus 5) it works, on the physical phones (an Huawei and a CUBOX) it doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I not implemented your solution, but my answer was referred to the normal functioning of Firebase's notifications.

Comment: I have not to implement it, however, it's a problem of physical devices, so I don't know why. Thank you for your effort, anyway!

Comment: Ok , but what happen? Have you issue on device registration?

Comment: No. On my emulator, I receive the messages, even if the app is swiped. On my two physical devices no, they receive it only if the app is running or is in background, and they don't receive the notification neither if I open the app after I sent the notification (thing that doesn't happen with my emulator).

Comment: @PAMAZ yes, i encountered my self this "issue" implementing Firebase Push , see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: Ok, I'll refer to you link. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you!